# Solve$(log_{2}(x+1))^2=4$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

$$(log_{2}(x+1))^2=4$$
$$log_{2}(x+1)*log_{2}(x+1)=log_{2}16$$
$$x^{2}+2x-15=0$$
$$(x+1)*(x+1)=16$$
$$x^{2}+2x+1=16$$
$$x^{2}+2x-15=0$$
$$(x+5)(x-3)=0$$
$$x_1=-5; x_2=3$$
The solution is only $x_1=3$. Is this correct?

Comment: Why isn't my way of solving this correct?

Comment: Because $\log(xy)\neq\log(x)\log(y)$

Comment: $$(logx)^2=logx\cdot\ logx$$ says in my book for maths.

Comment: $\log x\log x=(\log x)^2\neq\log(x^2)$

Comment: @Algean: I know that's not correct, I used $(logx)^2=logx\cdot\ logx$, not $log(xy)=log(x)log(y)$.

Comment: but $(log(x+1))^2=log 16$ doesn't follow that $(x+1)^2=16$

Comment: Now I see... So then my way of solving this isn't correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is incorrect. First note that
$$\log_2\left(a^2 \right) \neq \left(\log_2(a) \right)^2$$
In your case, we have
$$\left(\log_2(x+1) \right)^2 = 4 \implies \log_2(x+1) = \pm2 \implies x+1 = 2^{\pm2} \implies x+1 = 4 \text{ or }x+1= \dfrac14$$
Hence,
$$x=3 \text{ or }x=-\dfrac34$$

Answer (score 4):

If $$(\log_2(x+1))^2=4$$ then $$\log_2(x+1)=\color{red}{+2}$$ or $$\log_2(x+1)=\color{blue}{-2}$$ so $x+1=2^{\color{red}{+2}}$ or $x+1=2^{\color{blue}{-2}}$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: انشاء الله تبارک و تعالی :-)

Answer (score 2):

$$(\log_{2}(x+1))^2=4\iff\log_{2}(x+1)=\pm2$$
[1]$$\log_{2}(x+1)=2,x+1=2^2,x_1=3$$
[2]$$\log_{2}(x+1)=-2,x+1=2^{-2},x_2=-3/4$$

Comment: Nice to see Adi. Miss u at FB.

Answer (score 1):

$$ (\log_2(x+1))^2 = 4 \Rightarrow \log_2(x+1) = 2 , - 2 $$

$$ \Rightarrow x + 1 = 2^2 , 2^{-2} \Rightarrow x = 3 \space \textrm{or} \space -\frac{3}{4} $$